# updatepanel updating whole page instead of just the contenttemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
                        <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2"  ClientIDMode="AutoID" %>
                        <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head"        Runat="server">
                        </asp:Content>

                        <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="server">

                        <% 
                        foreach (var item in AllSales)
                        {
         //Here i have just set a breakpoint to see if it loops the AllSales list when I press the update button
                        }
                        %>

                        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
                        <ContentTemplate>

                        <p>Update Panel: DateTime.Now: <%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %></p>
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Submit" Text="Update" />

                        </ContentTemplate>

                        </asp:UpdatePanel>

                        </asp:Content>
```

The script manager code is in the masterpage :

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Problem here is that everytime i click the Update button it loads the page again and loops the "AllSales" list , i want to only update a section and not have to do unnecessary loops.

Here is the fun part : **If i remove the masterpage, it works ! But with the masterpage, it dont , why?!**

Comment: user runat server with input control instead user a asp:Button control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to recreate your problem but it is working fine in my case. Try creating a new .aspx file and paste the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <p>Outside UpdatePanel</p>
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <p>DateTime.Now: <%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %></p>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitButton" Text="Go" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This was tested in VS2010 using .NET 4.0 in an Empty Web Application. Does this work for you as well? I tried the same example using a Master page with a content placeholder. This yields the same (properly working) results. From this I gather there is something else going on on your page that we're missing. Is there?

**[Edit]**

I made another simple example, this time with a Master page and a Content page.

Master page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <p>Master Page: DateTime.Now: <%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %></p>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Aspx page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
<ContentTemplate>
<p>Update Panel: DateTime.Now: <%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %></p>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Submit" Text="Update" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Again this works without a problem in the same environment as the other example. It looks like you'll have to tell me about the .NET framework you're targeting and what else you've got set up in your master page and aspx page, because:

In .Net 3.5 and up this will work. In lower versions however, it won't. I'm afraid I've been unable to figure out how to fix it in lower versions though. :(

Comment: This is the closest one so far and it almost worked. When i tried your code, it worked perfectly, but when i added the aspx page to the masterpage, it failed. Is there something in the masterpage that is not correct u think?

Comment: When adding it to masterpage, i had to remove scriptmanager and form from your code because i have them in the masterpagem , but there it didnt work.

Comment: I updated my answer with another test, please check it out. Also: what framework are you targeting? What does the rest of your master page look like?

Comment: I tested your code with the masterpage but it still triggers the whole page to reload. See my edits in main post for the aspx.page code.

Comment: @syncis just add `ClientIDMode="AutoID"` that's it see my answer

Comment: @syncis can you check with just adding `ClientIDMode="AutoID"` in your Page Tag, believe that it would work

Comment: @syncis I'm unsure if you edited the main post properly? I don't see any updated code of your .aspx page.

Comment: @Korijn Now you see what i have in my Page, and everytime i click the button it loops the list.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a server control to initiate the update rather than a normal html input button. Try using:

```
<asp:Button ID="ActivitySubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I tried adding that, didnt work :(, did the same thing, it reloaded everything on the page instead of just the updatepanels controls.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `UpdateMode` mode property to Conditional. The default value for UpdateMode is `Always`, If the `UpdateMode` property is set to Always, the UpdatePanel control's content is updated on every postback that originates from anywhere on the page, [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode.aspx)

**Edit:** You are using input type="submit" which probably causing the post back replace it with asp:Button to get the ajax call to work.

Comment: I think you have misuderstood OP. I assume he complains about a full postback(with flickering page) although the submit-buttton is inside an `UpdatePanel`-control.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for such behavior is that you use plain html submit button instead of ASP.NET server button. Thus page submitted to server without involving ASP.NET Ajax functionality. Replace `ActivitySubmit` button with asp:Button control

Comment: I added the asp button but it still updated the whole pages controls instead of just the updatepanels, Have I maybe put the button on the wrong place or something?

Comment: Check my edit : <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />

Comment: Did you have any more ideas ? :/

Comment: @syncis how you detect that page completely reloaded? Try to add this line out of an UpdatePanel: `Page rendered at: <%= DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() %>` and check is it refreshed after click on button.

Comment: @Yuiry I have break points where i have other data loading so when i click on the button i break at the other places to and load the other data as well.

Comment: @syncis check this article: http://encosia.com/are-you-making-these-3-common-aspnet-ajax-mistakes/

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the same code with only change in the button type, and it refreshes only the update panel content. The problem is your site is targeting .NET 3.0 but you need to target at least to 3.5. I have tested on 3.0, it does not work but on 3.5 and 4.0, it works fine. So the easier and safer solution is to target 3.5 onwards. But If you want to use .NET 3.0, I will try to find a workaround. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Page` tag just add

```
ClientIDMode="AutoID"
```

Comment: Please see my main post, i added that to Page but still didnt work.

Comment: @syncis can you do one thing just share your code, so I could check as I test from my end, its working. and if I remove `ClientIDMode="AutoID" ` from `Page` it's not working. Share your code

Comment: Ok check the main post, problem is, if i remove the masterpage it works, with masterpage it dont work. Did I add the clientIDMode to right place?

Comment: ajax calls `page_load` each time. if you don't want to loop you could use  `if (!IsPostBack)`

Comment: you could refer a good explanation here http://encosia.com/are-you-making-these-3-common-aspnet-ajax-mistakes/

Comment: @syncis `Page_Load`, `Page_Render` do execute during every `partial postback`, it like `postback`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try and put the form inside the updatepanel, or you can try and change children as triggers property of the updatepanel like this :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" ChildrenAsTriggers="False">
```

and then add the button as trigger like this

```
   ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(SubmitButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

try addind this part to your UpdatePanel:

```
  <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Submit" />
  </Triggers>
```